# Align Div Text within form

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get the actionlink to align right for this code.

```
    <div style="height: 40px; background-image: url('/Images/page-title-bg.gif'); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-color: #EBEBEB; border: 1px solid Silver; border-top: 1px solid #f9f9f9; padding-left: 10px; box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);">
        <h1 style="border: none; line-height: 40px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;">
        Edit Publication @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Approve", null, new { style="text-align:right; font-size:12px;" })
        </h1>
    </div>
```

For some reason the text-align:right style is not working. I basically want the title on the left and the actionlink on the far right of the div.

This is the problem section

```
Edit Publication @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Approve", null, new { style="text-align:right; font-size:12px;" })
```

This is the html that is generated as per request

```
    <div style="height: 40px; background-image: url('/Images/page-title-bg.gif'); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-color: #EBEBEB; border: 1px solid Silver; border-top: 1px solid #f9f9f9; padding-left: 10px; box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);">
        <h1 style="border: none; line-height: 40px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;">
        Edit Publication <a href="/EPub/Approve" style="text-align:right; font-size:12px;">Back to List</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: how wide is your div? Maybe it is aligned right but the width of the div doesn't show it?

Comment: Please DO NOT show the server code, please show the output HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head...

```
h1 {
  overflow:hidden;
}
h1 span {
  float:left;
}
h1 a {
  float:right;
}

<h1><span>Title text</span> <a href="">Link text</a></h1>
```

... as quick guess. the overflow on the h1 should act as a clear for the 2 floats contained within.